# jQuery new added inputs are not submitted

Tags: jquery

I have a lot of PHP generated input fields. Once I add new fields with jQuery they are not submitted if they are empty. However the static ones are sent even if they are empty.

How should I fix that ?

**CODE:**

```
<form id="sendform" action="pdf.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="to1" />
<input type="text" name="to2" />
<input type="text" name="to3" />
<input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

Now jQuery part is:

```
var clone = $('input[name="to2"]').clone();
$(clone).attr('name', 'to4');
$('#sendform').append(clone);
```

**Screenshots:**
[image: This is what I see through DOM inspector]
[image: This is what I see in the headers when submitted]

You can see that there's Note1, Note2, Note3, Note4. I have added Note2 dynamically. You can see from the screenshot that it is in the dom, however it is not sent(yes, there's data inputted).

**SOLUTION**
In conclusion the problem was in  element placed inside the table(`<table><form>`). When  became parent of a table(`<form><table>`) - everything works fine.

Comment: Code..........? Are you talking about ajax? form submit? are they inside the `<form>`

Comment: Of course they are in <form> and submit means static form not AJAX. Also, code is not needed here. I explained the situation clearly. Basic DOM injection with .append() will not help

Comment: Your call, I', pretty sure you won't get an answer this way. good luck.

Comment: we cannot use our imagination to find the culprit.

Comment: Can you reproduce it in http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: I was getting the same issue with AJAX where the returned data had fields I wanted included in my form. Submit did not include the fields until I moved the <form> above the <table>. How stupid can HTML be?!?! I think that must be a bug.

Answer (score 4):

In case someone face same problem again - the reason can be pretty simple: malformed DOM.
This may lead to correct visual rendering but will not handle form inputs correctly on submit

If you have f.e.:

```
[form]
    [div]

    [div]
  [div] <!-- redundant closing div -->
[/form]
```

Newly appended form fields may not be sent.
Check page source in Firefox - red hinted tags may help you

Answer (score 2):

Works fine as expected:

```
var clone = $('input[name="to2"]').clone();
$(clone).attr('name', 'to4');
$('#sendform').append(clone);

$('#sendform').submit(function() {
    $('div').text($(this).serialize());
    return false;
});​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ugM2Y/)

Comment: But why didn't the code shown in the question work? I.e., why do the appended fields submit OK if non-empty?

Comment: I included screenshots of DOM and network headers. Despite the method I am using to create new element, you can see that newly created elements are not sent

Comment: @nnnnnn. My answer is: Look, if the code is as you posted it, it should work and works as expected.