# how to POST a ajax response in form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

**What I have done**
This is my ajax call and I get checkbox using this :

```
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#place").change(function(){
            var id = $(this).val();
            alert(id);
         $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "getsubcat.php",
            data: "pass_id="+id,
            success: function( data ) {
                  alert(data);

                document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = data;
    //$('#show').html(data);



            }
        });
    });
    });
    </script>
```

HERE is PHP CODE:

```
<?php
include_once 'config.php';
 $get_id=$_GET['pass_id'];

$data = array();
$sql="SELECT * FROM `app_subcategory` where cat_id='".$get_id."' ";

          $check= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$output.='<div class="form-group text-muted well well-sm no-shadow">
<p class="help-block">Please check atleast one Category.</p>                     
                      <lable><b>Categories</b></lable><br>';

          while($resultcheck= mysqli_fetch_array($check,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
 //$output .= ''.$resultcheck["subcategory_name"].'<input type="checkbox"  name="subcat" value="'.$resultcheck["id"].'" id="mycheckbox">';
  $output .= ' 
<div class="checkbox-inline">
                           <span style="margin-left:10px"></span><input name="subcat[]" value="'.$resultcheck["id"].'" type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox"><span>'.$resultcheck["subcategory_name"].'</span><span style="margin-left:10px"></span>
                      </div>';
}
  $otuput.='<br>

                  </div>
              </div>';    
print_r($output);
?>
```

My Requirement:

I want to POST this checkbox array result to another page using form add-place.php but when I click submit button I didn't get any data in POST which is showing using ajax .am new to ajax help me out and sorry for wrong English.

myoutputafter getting response
[image]

if there is another way to do it, please guide me.

This is my #place code

```
<?php  
$sql="SELECT * FROM `app_category` order by cat_id DESC ";

          $check= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
          $resultcheck= mysqli_fetch_array($check,MYSQLI_BOTH);

 ?>

<select id="place" name="place"  class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true"  style="color: #fff;" title="Choose here..."id="place" required >
<option id="default">--Select Place--</option>
<?php foreach($check as $pageid){?>



<option value="<?php echo $pageid['cat_id'];?>" id="<?php echo $pageid['cat_id'];?>"><?php echo $pageid['category_name']; ?></option>



<?php } ?></select></br>
             <p class="help-block">Please check atleast one Category.</p>                     
                      <lable><b>All Sub Categories</b></lable><br>
                      <div id="show"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: provide the `#place` html please

Comment: change `data: "pass_id="+id,` to `data: {"pass_id":id},`

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: @AswinRamesh - Both ways should work.

Comment: but when i click submit form it show null data in subcategory POST array

Comment: @JagdishSharma Well your AJAX is called when id="place" changes it value _(Not on form submit)_ which I can't find your in your code anywhere.

Comment: yes i am using ajax call to show the subcategory check boxes  see output image so user can select the sub category according to there need but when i post data in form the response checkbox data is not submitted with form

Comment: Is the checkbox checked when you submit the form? Checkboxes are only submitted if they are checked. If they aren't checked, they won't exist in the post data at all.

Comment: yes sir checkbox is checked when i submit data

Comment: How are you reading the post data? Please add that code as well. You need to add _all_ relevant code.

Comment: added my POST action code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this code**

So I research you problem a little bit and found out that an unclosed HTML element can cause such problem, I then check your below code and found an extra closing `div` tag.

> **REF:** [jQuery new added inputs are not submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286281/jquery-new-added-inputs-are-not-submitted)
>
> states that *"the reason can
>   be pretty simple: malformed DOM. This may lead to correct visual
>   rendering but will not handle form inputs correctly on submit."*

```
<?php
include_once 'config.php';
 $get_id=$_GET['pass_id'];

$data = array();
$sql="SELECT * FROM `app_subcategory` where cat_id='".$get_id."' ";

$check= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$output = ""; // <----------
// Added above line because php was generating:
// Notice: Undefined variable: output

$output.='
<div class="form-group text-muted well well-sm no-shadow">
    <p class="help-block">Please check atleast one Category.</p>                     
    <lable><b>Categories</b></lable><br>';

while($resultcheck= mysqli_fetch_array($check,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
 //$output .= ''.$resultcheck["subcategory_name"].'<input type="checkbox"  name="subcat" value="'.$resultcheck["id"].'" id="mycheckbox">';
  $output .= ' 
    <div class="checkbox-inline">
        <span style="margin-left:10px"></span>
        <input name="subcat[]" value="'.$resultcheck["id"].'" type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" />
        <span>'.$resultcheck["subcategory_name"].'</span>
        <span style="margin-left:10px"></span>
    </div>';
}
$output.='<br></div>'; 
// $otuput.='<br></div>';  //<------ TYPO
// Here was the extra </div>

print_r($output);
?>
```

Comment: thanks sir but the form am submitting is in modal and all div tag are properly closed now still did get data and any error help me out

Comment: I found another extra `</div>` just under `<div id="show"></div>` make sure it is balanced. Have you verified that you're AJAX call is appending your response to `id="show"` correctly.

Comment: @JagdishSharma Check the added line `$output = "";` in my answer.

Comment: sir can i mail you my files so i can understand problem correctly

Comment: Found a typo `$otuput.='<br></div>';` just above `print_r($output);`

Comment: Yes, you can but am not sure about the stackoverflow policy over sharing contact details

Comment: THANKS SIR GOT IT

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your "show" element is in form, which is suppose to get submitted and you are selecting one of the checkbox before submission.

`document.getElementById("show").innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

Ajax response doesn't update the document object model (DOM) that why when you will submit the form you will not get the element value which you received from the Ajax response

Here is the example which will create the element and update into the page DOM so that when you will submit the form you will get the element value in the POST request.

**PHP Script**

```
<?php
include_once 'config.php';
$get_id=$_GET['pass_id'];
$data = array();
$sql="SELECT * FROM `app_subcategory` where cat_id='".$get_id."' ";
$check= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$ar= [];
while($resultcheck= mysqli_fetch_array($check,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $ar[] = [
        'id' => $resultcheck["id"],
        'name' => $resultcheck["subcategory_name"],
    ];
}

echo json_encode($ar);
?>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#place").change(function(){
        var id = $(this).val();
        alert(id);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "getsubcat.php",
            data: {"pass_id":id},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function( data ) {
                var show = document.getElementById("show");
                //var obj = [{id:'1',name:'chk1'},{id:'2',name:'chk2'}];
                var div = document.createElement("DIV");       
                div.setAttribute('class','form-group text-muted well well-sm no-shadow');       
                var p = document.createElement("P");
                p.setAttribute('class','help-block');
                var pt = document.createTextNode("Please check atleast one Category."); 
                var label = document.createElement('label');
                var b = document.createElement('B');
                var bt = document.createTextNode("Categories"); 
                b.appendChild(bt);
                label.appendChild(b);
                p.appendChild(pt);
                var div2 = document.createElement("DIV");
                div2.setAttribute('class','checkbox-inline');
                jQuery.each(data,function(k,v){
                  var span0 = document.createElement("span");
                  span0.setAttribute('style','margin-left:10px');
                  var span = document.createElement("span");
                  span.setAttribute('style','margin-left:10px');
                  var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.setAttribute('name','subcat[]');
                input.setAttribute('type','checkbox');
                input.setAttribute('id','mycheckbox');
                input.setAttribute('value',v.id);
                var span1 = document.createElement("span");
                var span1t = document.createTextNode(v.name);
                span1.appendChild(span1t);
                div2.appendChild(span0);
                div2.appendChild(input);
                div2.appendChild(span1);
                }); 

                div.appendChild(p);
                div.appendChild(label);
                div.appendChild(div2);
                show.appendChild(div);

            }
        });
    });
    });
</script>
```